# Razor helper to render tr for property in List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a large amount of numerical data to spit out in a table from a List of complex objects 'Dto'. Each property in the Dto object needs a row in the table, for example...

```
     |dtos[0]|dtos[1]|dtos[2]|dtos[4]
prop1|   w   |   x   |   y   |   z
prop2|   a   |   b   |   c   |   d
```

Ideally I'd call a helper something like this...

```
@RenderTr("prop 1", model.Dtos, x => x.prop1);
@RenderTr("prop 2", model.Dtos, x => x.prop2);
```

...and it would loop through the Dtos list and spit out a td for each of the designated properties. Resulting in the following html...

```
<tr><td>prop 1</td><td>w</td><td>x</td><td>y</td><td>z</td></tr>
<tr><td>prop 2</td><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr>
```

I've tried looking into templated Razor delegates, helpers with fun and expression args but can't quite get my head around it.

**Updated question to make more sense.**

Comment: Create a `DisplayTemplate` for the model and use `DisplayFor(m => m.YourCollection)` to generate each `<tr>` and its `<td>` elements based on each item in the collection

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't think that'll do the trick? The collection is of complex objects, I need a row for each property, each column populated from one of the objects in the collection.

Comment: Of course it will - that's what an `EditorTemplate` is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach would be a custom extension method on HTMLHelper - passing in the row header, list of dtos and a member expression to let the method know which property you're after.

```
public static MvcHtmlString TableRowForProperty(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string rowName, IEnumerable<Financial> modelList, Expression<Func<Financial, decimal>> propertySelector)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb = sb.Append("<tr>");

    sb.Append($"<td>{rowName}</td>");

    foreach (var model in modelList)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;
        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(model);
        sb.Append($"<td>{value}</td>");
    }

    sb = sb.Append("</tr>");

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

You could make this a lot more generic, but this should be enough to get going with :)